# Apache Commons FileUtils.copyURLToFile - Directory that already exists could not be created

Tags: java, apache-commons, fileutils

I'm attempting to download a JSON file and save it to a local directory. The directory (/data/provisioning) already exists and has been given 776 (u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rw) as its permissions. The parent directory (/data) has also been given 776 permissions.

I'm using the Apache Commons FileUtils.copyURLToFile(..) method to download the file, like this:

```
String filePathToSave = "/data/provisioning/nexus_contents.json";
String url = "http://repository.obfuscated.com/nexus/url/to/json/file";

try {
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(
            new URL(url)
    , new File(filePathToSave),
            5000,
            5000);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, to my surprise, I'm getting this error:

> java.io.IOException: Directory '/data/provisioning' could not be
>   created   at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openOutputStream(FileUtils.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openOutputStream(FileUtils.java:319)
>     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyToFile(FileUtils.java:1552)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:1528)
>     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1506)
>     at
>   deployment.download.Downloader.getAndSaveNexusJSON(Downloader.java:26)
>     at
>   deployment.test.DeploymentTest.downloader_get_Nexus_JSON(DeploymentTest.java:424)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)     at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

What am I missing here?

Comment: What about permisions for apache?

Comment: Apache Commons is a Java library. I'm not doing anything with the Apache webserver.

Comment: This is likely a permissions issue. What happens if you write as a local path (and not a fully qualified one)?